# read TXT file with delimiter as ^@ using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a TXT and CSV files with delimiter as " ^@ " (was able to view this in VIM editor, in notepad++ it shows as null )
I want to use this as column separator for dataframe in Python(pandas). What should i use?

Answer (score 0):

`df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep='\^\@',engine='python')` 
Try this if it works!

Comment: Thank you Kranti for your response. I need it as a delimiter. In Pandas, it is giving me an error "delimiter must be 1-character string"

Comment: just replace sep with delimiter,.. it is working well with me,

Comment: Kranti, I change sep to delimiter, not working